# Passing Parameters and Populate Field Values (Optionset Value) in a New child case form on click of a ribbon button in mscrm

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Getting an error "**System.FormatException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #364D049C**" while setting optionset value on load of a child case form open on click of a ribbon button.

```
function SystemChildCaseButton() {
    try {
        debugger;
        var parameters = {};
        if (Xrm.Page.getControl("assa_childcasetype") && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("assa_childcasetype").getValue() != null) {
            var type = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("assa_childcasetype").getValue();
            if (type == 0)//Customer Care
            {
                parameters["formid"] = "4A63C8D1-6C1E-48EC-9DB4-3E6C7155334C";
                if (Xrm.Page.getControl("assa_casetype") && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("assa_casetype").getValue() != null) {
                    parameters["assa_casetype"] = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("assa_casetype").getValue();
                }

                if (Xrm.Page.getControl("assa_casetypedetail") && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("assa_casetypedetail").getValue() != null) {
                  parameters["assa_casetypedetail"] =  Xrm.Page.getAttribute("assa_casetypedetail").getValue();
                }
            }
  var options = { openInNewWindow: true };
        Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", null, parameters, options);
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Ananya, this is not really clear - please elaborate more - on which line is your code failing - is it when you save or when you open the form ? You should have stack trace - can you past it here also ?

Comment: I am getting this error on load of the child case form when I try to open the form on click of a ribbon button, if I comment the code for setting the value of optioset field, then it's working fine but it's giving me error while getting value of an optionset field in the line-    parameters["assa_casetype"] = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("assa_casetype").getValue();

Comment: The stack trace is:     <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #DFF53074</Message>
  <Timestamp>2018-05-30T06:49:31.5998327Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />

Comment: And the inner fault exception is:     <Message>System.FormatException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #364D049C</Message>

Comment: Did you check that optionset field is available/visible in form? You are checking some type as well? Also you are opening a particular form by passing formid in parameters.

Comment: Yes, the optionset field is available/visible in form , I am opening a child case form from a parent case form , on clicking ona ribbon button, so thereby passing parameters from the parent case form to the new child case form. All other parameters are getting set successfully, but when I pass these 2 fields, casetype and casetypedetail which are of type optionset, I am unable to open the form, it is giving me error.